# problems were placed firmly in bright sunlight

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In 20 years of studying psychological safety, my colleagues and I have amassed a solid body of evidence that organizations that explicitly value and make paths for speaking up happen are more effective in dealing with challenges of every kind. A handful of case studies in my 2019 book, The Fearless Organization, tell compelling stories about the kinds of learning and progress set in motion when **problems were placed firmly in bright sunlight** — and the catastrophes that ensued when they were not.

What does it mean?

Comment: bright sunlight: exposed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled the bold text and found that it only occurs in one [article](http://ttps://hbrascend.org/topics/dont-hide-bad-news-in-times-of-crisis/).

Your text in bold relates to the opening paragraph of the article:

> If sunshine is the best disinfectant, the opposite is also true: Dark,
>   hidden corners are great places to grow something truly horrible. Few
>   problems improve with age, and public health crises are no exception.
>   Transparency is “job one” for leaders in a crisis. Be clear what you
>   know, what you don’t know, and what you’re doing to learn more. You
>   can’t manage a secret, as the old saying goes.

The author is using sunlight and darkness as metaphor for transparency and concealment. Speaking in the context of the Covid-19 virus, the author states that sunlight (transparency) is the best disinfectant for viruses, while darkness (concealment) is a breeding ground for viruses. In this article, the virus is literally the problem. In other words, the author is saying that the best way to eliminate a problem is by transparency.

So when the author refers to "placing problems firmly in the bright sunlight", she is referring to opening up about problems. In the broader context of the paragraph, she is saying that being open about problems will help eliminate them, while hiding problems only leads to them getting worst. This relates back to the analogy of sunlight being the disinfectant and darkness being the breeding ground for "something truly horrible".